# Unix command (grep, sed or awk): output as input and search a file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I would very much appreciate if someone can help me.

I would like to perform this task using some commands, either grep, sed, or awk (or something else). 
I have two in-files.

File 1

```
0  
1  
4
```

File 2

```
S   0   1832    *   0   *   *   *  
S   1   1801    *   0   *   *   *  
H   1   1298    99.2    +   0   0   301M10I997M493I  
S   2   1791    *   0   *   *   *  
S   3   1720    *   0   *   *   *  
S   4   1693    *   0   *   *   *  
S   11  1693    *   0   *   *   *
```

The output what I want is

```
S   0   1832    *   0   *   *   *  
S   1   1801    *   0   *   *   *  
H   1   1298    99.2    +   0   0   301M10I997M493I  
S   4   1693    *   0   *   *   *
```

So, if the second column of file2 matched with file1 lines, extract to the output. This is what I want to do.

Comment: awk is perfect, look in this direction. There are plenty of reply to similar question here to start/do your code.

Comment: I have used 
cat File1.txt | grep -f - File2.txt 
But cannot specify the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the classic solution in awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ a[$1]; next }$2 in a{ print $0 }' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
S   0   1832    *   0   *   *   *  
S   1   1801    *   0   *   *   *  
H   1   1298    99.2    +   0   0   301M10I997M493I  
S   4   1693    *   0   *   *   *
```

The first part of the command is only executed on file1 due to the pattern FNR==NR which is only true for file1. It uses $1 as an index for the array a. The next command checks if $2 of file2 is in as an index in the array. $2 in file2 the desired match. And the last command prints the whole matching line of file2.

Comment: you can remove `{print $0}`, as it is the default action

Comment: @user2182606, you can accept the answer if it had solved your issue